# Ziggy - Make a square from 8 polyomino pieces

Tags: no-computers, polyomino, packing

A few years ago I created a small packing puzzle that I'd like to share here today. The puzzle is based on the fact that $1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8 = 6^2$. It consists of 8 zig-zag polyomino pieces, ranging in size from 1 to 8 squares. The pieces are shown here:

[image]

The basic aim is to create a 6 by 6 square.

[image]

There are two very closely related solutions.

Comment: It is quite fun to solve this by hand, so I recommend cutting out the pieces out of cardboard. When the puzzle has been solved I will link to a page with further shapes you can make instead of just the square.

Comment: As promised, here is a link to some further problems you can solve with these pieces: [Ziggy page](https://www.jaapsch.net/g4g/g4g12.htm)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one solution.

> [image]

The second solution can be achieved by:

> Swapping the 4 and 6.

.

> [image]

Comment: You write *the* second solution, which seems to imply that there are only two of them?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni they're referring to the two similar solutions the OP is talking about.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one solution

> [image: gosh I'm bad at making little papers]

Thanks for the fun!

Bonus shapes:

> [image: bonus1]

> [image: bonus2]

Comment: You got the same as my first solution. (And even the same rotation/reflection, coincidentally) Good job on actually cutting out pieces.

Comment: @Riley I just follow Jaap Scherphuis advice, and it was indeed quite fun.